# Converting PLPGSQL functions to Python class methods

Tags: python, postgresql, plpgsql, psycopg2

Let's say I have written bunch of functions in PLPGSQL. How to fetch all those functions with Python code with psycopg2 library?

Please see below example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_player_by_email(email_adress varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, email varchar, nick varchar)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
        'SELECT players.id, players.email, nick
        FROM players
        WHERE players.email = $1'
        USING email_adress;
    RETURN;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql stable;
```

Why I need this? I have Python class with **init** that connects to my database. I would like to add following functionality in **init**: browse all functions, and create new methods in the fly with those function names, which return exactly what plpgsql functions do. For example, I would like to have get_player_by_email method generated automatically:

```
Class MyDatabase(object):
    def get_player_by_email(self, email):
        pass
```

Comment: The answer is way too big. You will need to break the problem down into much smaller chunks.

Comment: So let's say I want to browse all functions in my database from python code with psycopg2 library, I think it is a good way to start.

Comment: Yes, that is a good start. Rewrite it and give a hint to the final goal in a small paragraph at the end like a footnote.

Comment: Done, my footnote ended up quite big, but I think my question meets the SO standards now, if not, please do not hesitate to mention it, I will adjust once again.